# Pace.js(Progress bar) for Ajax request is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, progress-bar, pace.js

In the documentation, it is written that you don't need to write code in general to use it. I have added that in my website, It is working fine on page load. But for any ajax request, it is not working. Do I need to add anything for ajax request?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Which theme do you use? do you use jQuery's ajax everytime or any other framework?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case you will need  `$(document).ajaxStart(function() { Pace.restart(); });`

http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3ff/2865/

Comment: This is the example, when I run this code it works perfectly fine but not in the case of ajax request.
http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3ff/2857/

Comment: This is what I need, Thanks for quick reply :)